# Excel Not Transferring Data to Access Database

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, vba

I have a table in in Access 2010 that stores project information. The main columns - for this purpose - are `LocationID`, `Priority1`, and `Priority2` (which have proper names but for generalization...)

I also have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that has this information to be exported into Access. What it does is run through the `LocationID` columns in Excel and Access, and colours all the matching fields. Then it checks the `Priority1` and `Priority2` columns to see if any of the rows are already filled in, and colours the ones that aren't. This part works fine.

What it's supposed to do *next* is copy the values from two `Priority` columns that are coloured from Excel into the Access table. This isn't happening, and I'm not sure why.

The entire code is fairly long, so here's just the section concerning transferring values. I can add any other code that might be useful.

```
If (Not (IsNull(path))) Then
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & path & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "BCIImport", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(Range("B" & r).Formula) > 0
        With rs
            If Not rs.BOF Then
                rs.MoveFirst
            End If

            If (Range("B" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)) Then
                .AddNew
                .Fields("LocationID") = Range("B" & r).Value
                .Fields("Priority1") = Range("C" & r).Value
                .Fields("Priority2") = Range("D" & r).Value
                .Update
            End If
        End With
        r = r + 1 'advances to next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End If
```

I'm not much of a VBA programmer, so any advice would be great.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next`, then run the code again and see what happens. (I'm assuming you set `r` to a valid value at some point prior to this code?)

Comment: Yes, `r` is defined as `r=2` at the beginning. This is still returning blank fields.

Comment: Once you've figured out what the error is, take that commented-out `On Error Resume Next` line, and remove it. Then make a quick search on this site about error handling in VBA. The best way to never know what's going on is to use `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: If you're not getting any errors but getting blank fields in the database, there's a good chance you just need so specify the worksheet the code should be using - i.e. using `Worksheets("foo").Range(...).Value`, rather than just using `Range(...).Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your code triggers a primary key violation when attempting to add a new row with a *LocationID* value which matches the *LocationID* value of another row.  This is where the new row is added:

```vb
.AddNew
.Fields("LocationID") = Range("B" & r).Value
```

Since you have this earlier in the procedure ...

```vb
On Error Resume Next
```

... Access does not inform you about the problem which prevented that row from being added.

Test my guess by disabling that `On Error` line, as the other comments recommended:

```vb
'On Error Resume Next
```

I suspect you will need a strategy which first checks whether the current *LocationID* value is already stored in the table.  If it is present, update that existing row.  And if not present, add a new row ... something like this ...

```vb
If DCount("*", "BCIImport", "LocationID=" & Range("B" & r).Value) = 0 Then
    ' add new row
Else
    ' update existing row
End If
```